# Python - Group class objects in lists according to attributes

Tags: python, class, object, linked-list, grouping

I am facing a challenging to subdivide a list with objects (class) into two lists according to connections index:

Each item in the list is a class object that contains, ex:

```
Obj1.a = var
Obj1.b = [1, 12]
```

See pseudo list with objects below:

list= [  **[[var, [1, 12]]**, [var, [2, 0]], **[var, [3, 1]]**, [var, [4, 2]], **[var, [5, 3]]**, [var, [7, 4]], [var, [11, 8]], **[var, [12, 10]]**, [var, [0, 11]], [var, [19, 13, 7]], **[var, [5, 18, 17]]**, [var, [21, 19]], **[var, [20, 17]]**, [var, [21, 22]],  **[var, [23, 20]]**, [var, [28, 22]], **[var, [26, 23]]**, [var, [13, 8, 28]], **[var, [10, 26,18]]**  ]

1. Note that the method b returns 2 or 3 index numbers.
2. The sequence is not in order.

The goal is from item 1 in the list, check the next item (“item 2”) that has at least one index in common, then appended “item 2” to a new list. Next, take “item 2” and make the same, and so on…

In the code above I marked the items that should be grouped together in bold. 
Any ideas?

Output:

```
list_A = [ [[var, [1, 12]], [var, [3, 1]], [var, [5, 3]], [var, [12, 10]], [var, [5, 18, 17]], [var, [20, 17]], [var, [23, 20]], [var, [26, 23]], [var, [10, 26,18]] ]

list_B = [ [var, [2, 0]], [var, [4, 2]], [var, [7, 4]], [var, [11, 8]], [var, [0, 11]], [var, [19, 13, 7]], [var, [21, 19]], [var, [21, 22]],  [var, [28, 22]], [var, [13, 8, 28]] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solve the problem partially, but I would like to return both lists not only one. Also if we pass the function again changing the elem the result is an empty list. Any ideas? See code below:**

```
    list_total = [[1000, [1, 12]], [2000, [2, 0]],
                  [1000, [3, 1]] , [2000, [4, 2]],
                  [1000, [5, 3]] , [2000, [7, 4]], 
                  [2000, [11, 8]], [1000, [12, 10]], 
                  [2000, [0, 11]], [2000, [19, 13, 7]],
                  [1000, [5, 18, 17]], [2000, [21, 19]],
                  [1000, [20, 17]], [2000, [21, 22]],
                  [1000, [23, 20]], [2000, [28, 22]],
                  [1000, [26, 23]], [2000, [13, 8, 28]],
                  [1000, [10, 26,18]]]

    def chain(lst, elem):

        if elem in lst:
           lst.remove(elem)

        for e1 in elem[1]:
            for e2 in lst:
                if e1 in e2[1]:
                    chain(lst, e2)                

        level = lst
        return level

    level_A = chain(list_total, list_total[0])
    print ("level_A: ", level_A)

    level_B = chain(list_total, list_total[1])
    print ("level_B: ", level_B)


    output: level_A:  [[2000, [2, 0]], [2000, [4, 2]], [2000, [7, 4]],
                       [2000, [11, 8]], [2000, [0, 11]], [2000, [19, 13, 7]], 
                       [2000, [21, 19]], [2000, [21, 22]], 
                       [2000, [28, 22]], [2000, [13, 8, 28]]]

            level_B:  []
```